# Improving speed of Animation class

Tags: java, game, animation

This is a class to hold an animation and be able to refer to different animations by titles, but it seems like calling `draw(Graphics2D g)` and `update` every frame, would, with this implementation, cause a big slowdown with all the `list.get(Object obj)` calls. Is this a big deal, and if so how should I change the implementation? Other comments on the code are very welcome.

```
package core.graphics;

import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;


public class AnimationSet {

    private int currentAnimation;

    private Map<String, Integer> namesToAnimation;
    private List<Animation> animations;

    public AnimationSet() {
        currentAnimation = 0;
        namesToAnimation = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
        animations = new ArrayList<Animation>();
    }
    public void addAnimation(String title, Animation animation){
        animations.add(animation);
        namesToAnimation.put(title, animations.size()-1);
    }
    public void goToAnimation(String title){
        currentAnimation = namesToAnimation.get(title);
    }
    public void removeAnimation(String title){
        animations.remove(namesToAnimation.get(title));
        namesToAnimation.remove(title);
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g, int x, int y){
        g.drawImage(animations.get(currentAnimation).getImage(), x, y, null);
    }
    public void update(){
        animations.get(currentAnimation).update();;
    }        
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your `List` is instantiated as an `ArrayList`, the lookup time for `get` is constant time, \$O(1)\$.

There is however, somethings that I can point out.

## Final

Whenever possible, add the keyword `final` to member fields of your class. This keyword should be used for values/references that never change. Your `namesToAnimation` and `animations` variables can be marked with **`final`**.

## Why `Map<String, Integer>`?

You seem to only use your `namesToAnimation` as a lookup for `String` to `index in the 'animations' list`. You never increase/decrease your `currentAnimation` value. Then why do you use `Map<String, Integer>`? I think you can get rid of your list entirely and use `Map<String, Animation>`

#### Rewritten code according to what I have mentioned above:

```
public class AnimationSet {

    private Animation currentAnimation;
    private final Map<String, Animation> animations;

    public AnimationSet() {
        animations = new HashMap<>();
    }
    public void addAnimation(String title, Animation animation){
        animations.put(title, animation);
    }
    public void goToAnimation(String title){
        currentAnimation = animations.get(title);
    }
    public void removeAnimation(String title){
        animations.remove(title);
    }
    public void draw(Graphics2D g, int x, int y){
        g.drawImage(currentAnimation.getImage(), x, y, null);
    }
    public void update(){
        currentAnimation.update();
    }        
}
```

#### Usefulness

I'm sorry, but I can't really understand why you have this class? What functionality does it provide to you? Would it be easier to have the same functionality without this class?

Hopefully you have a good use case for this class, in which case, great! I'm just not sure how I myself would use this class, which brings me to the next point:

#### Documentation

Although your naming is really good (you have no idea how happy I am to be able to say that!), your class could use some documentation in the form of [JavaDoc](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/documentation/index-137868.html). Stating the purpose of the class and the usage of the class and it's methods in JavaDoc helps any potential users of your class, it can even help yourself several times.

#### Thread safety

Your code would likely cause problems if it would be used from multiple threads. To avoid those problems, learn about [Java Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/). If you're not using multiple threads now, you might be later, that's why I'm mentioning this. It's something for you to learn in the future :)

Comment: Good answer, as an additional point: I'd initialize final members right where they are declared if they don't depend on constructor parameters.